# JavaScript about syntax error? (codecedemy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error

I'm doing Codeacademy JavaScript course and I'm doing okay. I've been able to solve my problems on my own until now. I just can't get it right.

Heres my code 
**JavaScript**

```
 var main = function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();

        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts')
        $('.status-box').val(''),
 });

    $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <p class="counter">140</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="posts">
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript code isn't working. It's supposed to make a character count for how many characters there are left to be used in the textbox. Problem is the code isn't working. Remember I'm a beginner so try to be as clear as possible when presenting a solution to my problem. I think that the problem is small error somewhere in the JavaScript code, but I just can't find it since my JavaScript understanding isn't optimal yet. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to start using browser console for debugging. It will help you finding these little syntax errors :)

Comment: Im completly fresh to web dev. started out yesterday, but if you'd like to explain what broswer console is, id be glad to try it out

Comment: It is the same like if you program desktop applications. It will log compilation or runtime errors and lead you to the line number, function name etc that caused the error. You can read about it on this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just bad syntax of extra comma, here is the fixed version:

```
 var main = function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();

        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
    });

    $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very small, just a syntax error, look at this:

`$('.status-box').val(''),`

Change it to

`$('.status-box').val('');`